# Unable to request channel Iax2/3002 while calling to asterisk server

Tags: java, asterisk, asteriskami, agi

I am trying to make a call to asterisk server from my AGI. My AGI is basically a java code which uses Asterisk-java.jar library for communication with asterisk server. I opened up the connection with asterisk server and ran some commands on it and I got right response from the server. Now , when I try to make the call to the asterisk server, using the following code

```
     OriginateAction act = new OriginateAction();
        act.setChannel ("IAX2/3002");
        act.setContext ("default");
        act.setExten ("3002");
        act.setPriority (new Integer(1));
        act.setAsync (true);
        act.setTimeout(3000l);
        return mc.sendAction(act);
```

I got following on my serverCLI :

```
     == Manager 'salman' logged on from 127.0.0.1
     [Sep 12 19:39:14] NOTICE[12093]: channel.c:5619 __ast_request_and_dial: Unable to request channel IAX2/3002
     == Manager 'salman' logged off from 127.0.0.1
```

Why is it saying "Unable to request channel IAX2/3002"? I have configured my manager.conf, I have a dialplan in my extensions.conf and I have created a user on iax.conf. Please help!

my manager.conf file:

```
       [general]
       enabled = yes
       ;webenabled = yes
       port = 5038
       bindaddr = 0.0.0.0

       [salman]
       secret=salman
       permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
       read=all
       write=all
```

my extension.conf file :

```
     [general] 
     static=yes
     writeprotect=yes 
     clearglobalvars=no
     autofallthrough=yes
     priorityjumping=no

     [default]

     exten => 3001,1,Answer()
     exten => 3001,2,Playback(/home/salman/Test_sound_file/main_menu)
     exten => 3001,3,Hangup()
```

And my Iax.conf file:

```
    [general]

    bandwidth=medium
    disallow=all
    allow=alaw
    trunkmaxsize=128000
    trunkmtu=1240
    iaxthreadcount=100
    iaxmaxthreadcount=512
    autokill=yes
    trunkfreq=20
    srvlookup=no
    codecpriority=host

    [3002]
    type=friend
    context=default
    secret=3002
    callerid=3002
    requirecalltoken=no
    host=dynamic
    nat=yes
    canreinvite=no
    mailbox=1000@default
```

Answer (score 0):

the above error shows that you have no registered user, It doesn’t only mean that you did not register it in iax.conf, Use twinkle or any other soft phone and register it with account 3002 and then execute you will get a call to the soft phone. The context in iax.conf should be [default] not [3002]